# I need regex validation for edittext which allow only when edittext have one character and one digit atleast

Tags: android

Check that edittext have combination of character and digit

Answer (score 0):

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                editText.getText().toString().trim();
                // MATCH IT HERE WITH THAT REGEX
                // COMBINATION OF ONE LETTER AND ONE DIGIT ([a-zA-Z])(\d)
                // COMBINATION OF LETTERS AND DIGITS AFTER ([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```